# How are services mapped to the files in /etc/pam.d?

Tags: linux, security, authentication, pam

How does pam decide which files in /etc/pam.d to use depending on whether a user logs in via ssh, locally, a serial console, etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PAM "service" name ("sshd", "sudo", etc.) is compiled into the application.  That is what decides which file will be initially loaded.  After that, the @include lines are processed as described in freiheit's post.

Answer (score 5):

It might be hardcoded into the programs, but each service has its own file in /etc/pam.d generally named after the actual process name. Local and serial consoles both work via getty which passes off actual logging in to "login", so you'd need to look at /etc/pam.d/login.  SSH is actually "sshd", so it's in /etc/pam.d/sshd

On most modern distros, those files mostly contain lines like "@include common-password" or "auth include system-auth", so for those two you'd then need to look at /etc/pam.d/common-password or /etc/pam.d/system-auth.  Slightly older distros (RHEL3, for instance), use something like "auth required pam_stack.so service=system-auth", which is a module based version of the same thing.

Comment: Slightly older systems use the pam_stack.so module for this.

Comment: oh yeah.  I'll update.